# Show value column in stead of key column as label in QGIS 2.14

Tags: qgis, labeling, qgis-2.14

I'm using QGIS 2.14. I have a field defined as a value relation (widget). I would
like to show the value in the linked "value column" as a label in the map in stead of the value of the "key column". Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer myself. This should be the label-expression:

> attribute(get_feature('VALUE_LAYER_NAME', 'KEY_FIELD', KEY),
>   'VALUE_FIELD')
>
> VALUE_LAYER_NAME: the name of the layer having the value column (the
>   linked layer)
>
> KEY_FIELD: the name of the key column in the VALUE_LAYER_NAME
>
> KEY: the name of the field in the layer you are labeling (the one with
>   the value relation defined)
>
> VALUE_FIELD: the name of the value column in the VALUE_LAYER_NAME